# Boolean value if logged in

Tags: php, authentication

I'm trying to make a login page and not letting the user to reaccess by hitting the back button, I'm using PHP

In concrete i want to store a boolean `$loggedIn` in the session and  destroy the session when they log out. Check on each page to make sure they're logged in, otherwise redirect to the login page, and I wanted a method other than `$_GET` for obvious security reasons.

How can I do this ?

Comment: You have all of the psuedo-code in your question. Just go an implement it piece by ice.

Comment: If you know of `$_GET`, you know of `$_POST`, I presume.  If you know of SO, you know that trying and presenting your code is pro-forma, I presume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, storing the login info in the $_GET method i.e. the URL is not a good practice at all. You can either store it in a php session variable or using cookies.

here is a good tutorial for using php sessions

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

and this is for the cookie

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp

Comment: why did my post get voted down?I'm a senior php coder and I know that there is nothing wrong in my answer.The person who asked the question realizes that it isn't secure to authenticate the user based on a value coming from $_GET method, so he asked for an alternative. The typical practice for his case is to store data in sessions or cookies. I gave URL to walk him through working with sessions.

when you people vote down the correct answer then how can others benefit from it? if you think there is something wrong in the suggested solution you can comment on it and point to what it is wrong!

Comment: A lot of people on SO shun when a answer/comment is made with a link to w3schools.